# Gradle "private" configuration per developer

Tags: build, gradle

For local development our developers should be able to define a task (copying the final jar into a specific directory) with a custom configuration. Some people do not need this task so we don't want to put it into our build.gradle.

Is it possible to add any "custom" configuration to a gradle project so that we can simply ignore a file in our CVS? If not, what could be good way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines could work:

```
def username = System.getProperty('user.name')
def userGradleScript = file("gradle/user/${username}.gradle")
if (!userGradleScript.exists()) {
    //Create a file from template and replace %username% in file
    userGradleScript.write(file('gradle/user/template.gradle').text.replaceAll('%username%', username))
}
apply from: userGradleScript
```